# Drawing a line to a point - style in QGIS

Tags: qgis, style, geometry-generator

I need to create a style in QGIS in which the line is moved away from the second line by 2 units, but their ends merge at one point. I created 3 geometry generators - 3 lines.
At the ends of the line:

```
 make_line(
project(  
    start_point(  $geometry ), 
    2/cos(radians(30)), radians(60)+  azimuth(  make_point(  $x_at( 0), $y_at( 0)),  
    make_point(  $x_at( 1), $y_at( 1)))),  start_point(  $geometry ))

 make_line(
project(  
    start_point(  $geometry ), 
    2/cos(radians(30)), radians(60)+  azimuth(  make_point(  $x_at( 0), $y_at( 0)),  
    make_point(  $x_at( 1), $y_at( 1)))),  start_point(  $geometry ))
```

and offset line:

```
 difference( 
 difference( 
     $geometry ,  buffer(  end_point(  $geometry ), 2*tan(radians(30)))), 
     buffer(  start_point(  $geometry ), 2*tan(radians(30))))
```

It looks ok, but there are also errors eg when the last episode is shorter than the offset
[image]

Is there any way that the style will always work correctly and that the line will always be tightened to the starting point?